# How to set formControlNames using *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, ngfor

I'm trying to set form control using `*ngFor` over objects in an Array. Depending on the users sometimes I will have 1 object in the Array but other times multiple.

My issue is that I want to create a `formControlName` using the loop which I can but not sure how to set form group validators in the component? Just setting them like below means if there is only 1 object the form remains invalid while looking for the other `formControlName` that does not exist.

So if the first object with name:"Days" isn't in the list, "Days" would still be in `this.form` and shows up in controls:

**Array:**

```
indicators = [
  {name:"Days",data:[250,1]},
  {name:"Multiply Average",data:[3,.25,1]}
],
```

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this._fb.group({
            "Multiply Average":['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required
                ])],
            "Days":['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required
                ])],
        });  
    };
```

**Template:**

```
  <span
     *ngFor="let i of indicators">
          {{i.name}}: 
          <md-slider
            formControlName={{i.name}}
            color="primary"
            [max]=i.data[0]
            [thumb-label]="true"
            [step]=i.data[1]
            [min]=i.data[2]>
          </md-slider>
  </span>
```

Any help would be great

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for the reply. Sorry I should have been more clear. I want to be able to pass a variable amount of dictionaries to the indicators array. I know it works currently with two. If I were to pass only `{name:"Days",data:[250,1]}` however there would still be form control for `Multiply Average` in the component. The template would only have a slider for `Days`. Is there some way to update both sort of dynamically like the loop does? I'm not sure if it's possible if you don't know the length of indicators array? Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like you need `FormArray`, but I can't really say further, since I'm not sure how the array could look and I don't know what that `data` array inside the object is. What is the expected output exactly? what value should the formcontrol hold, just name?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try do a plunkr now for it to make it more clear. I haven't done one before but should be able to work it out

Comment: I did one for the whole component https://plnkr.co/edit/3wg4SUncFbJ8r1OJ1nrf?p=info. So basically the issue is that a user selects a stock indicator to use and different indicators will require a different number of sliders (user input) to send of to my API.  I know you could write code for each individual slider but I wanted to use a loop if possible? Just because I don't want to write more code every time I add another indicator to the indicators array? The code updates everything in the template but no idea how to make the control FormBuilder change based on the selected indicator. Cheers

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce the issue, what is the contents of your arrays for example. Set sample data please that, sample data where the issue is shown, which the current `indicators` in your question doesn't?

Comment: Please make a working plunker, here's a template for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/vMCn7M8NlIPm1EEyaTEy?p=preview

Comment: Cheers for the template. I finally got the plnkr working properly: https://plnkr.co/edit/e8Sj3eaOWuSrepcmw5qY?p=preview . So users can select an indicator from `md-select` and an array of data for that indicator is passed to a loop to create one or more `md-slider`. The issue is form control on the sliders. If `New High - Close Price` is selected for indicator than only `{name:"Days",data:[250,1]}` slider is created but formControl for "Multiply Average" continues to make form INVALID. Is there a way to update FormBuilder based on the user selection? Thanks again for helping I appreciate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is conditional validation. Depending on choice you need to set the wanted validators, or then remove them. This here is a very simple example to give you the idea, if you have several more fields, more validations etc I suggest you take a look at this: ["**How to implement conditional validation in Angular model-driven forms**"](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-conditional-validation-in-angular-2-model-driven-forms)

There is sample of iterating through form controls and making the whole thing more dynamic, but the idea is the same as below.

We can set a change event on when user makes choice in the `md-select`. You could of course also use `valueChanges`, but I like a simple change event:

```html
<md-select
  formControlName="indicator1"
  (change)="checkValue(form.get('indicator1'))">
  <md-option
      *ngFor="let indicator of indicators['indicatorlist']" 
       [value]="indicator">
       {{indicator}}
  </md-option>   
</md-select>
```

We pass the form control so that we can compare it with the value of which validators should be removed in case it doesn't match, in this case we want to remove validator is the value is something else than `Above WMA - Volume Price`. We set/unset the validators and we also need to use `updateValueAndValidity()` here:

```ts
checkValue(ctrl) {
  if(ctrl.value != "Above WMA - Volume Price") {
    this.form.get('Multiply Average').setValidators(null);
    this.form.get('Multiply Average').updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    this.form.get('Multiply Average').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.form.get('Multiply Average').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Instead of `setValidators(null)` you can also just use `clearValidators()`

As already mentioned, this is a very crude sample to just give you the idea.

Now in the plunker, if you choose something else than `Above WMA - Volume Price` from the drop down, the form will now be considered valid (if other fields are valid), even though there is no value in that form control with name `Multiply Average`.

**DEMO:** https://plnkr.co/edit/h4nQfg1VYykaGgfNfnWk?p=preview

Comment: Wow thanks heaps for this! I knew there must be some way but had no idea

Comment: Hey, glad to hear it worked! Yes, reactive forms have many very cool features. You can do basically anything with a reactive form, hah! Just takes a while to get to grips with all the things you can do and all the methods that are built in. :) But yeah, have a good end of the weekend and happy coding!

Comment: Yeah i'm still relatively new to Angular so still discovering a lot! It's definitely a better end to the weekend getting this problem solved haha so thanks again

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `[formGroup]="form"` on your `form` tag.

Also to make it more verbose use property binding instead of interpolation over `formControlName` attribute

```
[formControlName]="i.name"
```

Comment: i.name wont show as static.
<input formControlName="i.name".. It is not working.